# set TextView in a center vertical and horizontal

Tags: android

I need set textView10 at center of vertical and horizontal. I've tried a lot without results... I tried with gravity options but nothing.. any idea? textView10 is within scrollview. Thanks for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#000000"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="151dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textSize="15pt" />

  <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scrollView10"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#000000" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView10"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textSize="13sp"
      android:textStyle="italic" />

  </ScrollView>      

 </LinearLayout>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button10"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Chiudi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="15pt" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Hi What is your name"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chiudi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your outer layout to RelativeLayout and position yout ScrollView at the parent center. Position other elements in relation to one in center

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="15pt" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000000" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 cause this solution doesn't involve a fixed layout height of the TextView. The outer RelativeLayout can be set to any size/position and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Put the TextView inside of a RelativeLayout, and put that RelativeLayout inside of the ScrollView.

Then, set android:layout_centerInParent="true" within the TextView